# How do I generate my list of datetime elements without getting parentheses around each element?

Tags: python, pandas, list, datetime, parentheses

I've created an empty list and appended datetime elements to it using a loop. When I check the list, each element has extra parentheses surrounding it.

Here's my code:

```
dates = []
day_count = 70
start_date = dt.date(2019, 6, 1)

for single_date in (start_date + dt.timedelta(n) for n in range(day_count)):
    datetime = single_date
    dates.append(datetime)

dates
```

Which yields:

```
[(datetime.date(2019, 6, 1),),
(datetime.date(2019, 6, 2),),
(datetime.date(2019, 6, 3),),
```

Rather than

```
[datetime.date(2019, 6, 1),
datetime.date(2019, 6, 2),
datetime.date(2019, 6, 3),
```

I presume that the solution will be something pretty simple, but if it's not, I'll happily take a solution for how to remove those extra parentheses. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Try using pandas date_range function? `pd.date_range('2019-06-01', periods=70, freq='D')`

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem. I get your desired output with your above code.

Comment: because with your weird loop you are iterating in a list of tuple (with each tuple being one element) instead of iterating through a list of dates

Comment: I realized I had `datetime = single_date,` rather than `datetime = single_date` in my actual code. D'oh! Thanks everyone, I'll use Scott Boston's method!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```py
dates = []
day_count = 70
start_date = dt.date(2019, 6, 1)

my_list = []
for n in range(day_count):
    my_list.append(start_date + dt.timedelta(n))

for single_date in my_list:
    datetime = single_date
    dates.append(datetime)
dates
```